# Remove uncommon words in columns of two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2.

`df1` looks like this:

```
id   text
1    I love this car
2    I hate this car
3    Cars are life
4    Bikers are also good
```

`df2` looks like this:

```
id   text
1    I love this supercar
2    I hate cars
3    Cars are love
4    Bikers are nice
```

Now, I want to keep only those words that are in `df1` and `df2`.

The word `car` is in `df1` but not in `df2`, so I want to remove it.

The word `life` is in `df1` but not in `df2`, so I want to remove it.

The word `also` is in `df1` but not in `df2`, so I want to remove it.

The word `good` is in `df1` but not in `df2`, so I want to remove it.

The word `supercar` is in `df2` but not in `df1`, so I want to remove it.

The word `nice` is in `df2` but not in `df1`, so I want to remove it.

Expected output of df1:

```
id   text
1    I love this
2    I hate this
3    Cars are
4    Bikers are
```

Expected output of `df2`

```
id   text
1    I love this
2    I hate cars
3    Cars are love
4    Bikers are
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create intersection of words in both columns and then remove not matched values:

```
a = set([y for x in df1['text'] for y in x.split()])
b = set([y for x in df2['text'] for y in x.split()])
c = a & b
print (c)
{'hate', 'are', 'Bikers', 'this', 'love', 'I', 'Cars'}

df1['text'] = df1['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split() if y in c))
df2['text'] = df2['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split() if y in c))
print (df1)
   id         text
0   1  I love this
1   2  I hate this
2   3     Cars are
3   4   Bikers are

print (df2)
   id           text
0   1    I love this
1   2         I hate
2   3  Cars are love
3   4     Bikers are
```